# ViewPager is not Showing and No Exception through NullPointerException in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I am trying to show view pager but the view pager is not showing. I am new in android developing Please help me :

My HomeFragment.java:-

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


TextView tvId01,tvId02,tvId03,tvId04,tvId05,tvId06;
TextView tvName01,tvName02,tvName03,tvName04,tvName05,tvName06;
TextView tvPrice01,tvPrice02,tvPrice03,tvPrice04,tvPrice05,tvPrice06;
TextView tvMainPrice01,tvMainPrice02,tvMainPrice03,tvMainPrice04,tvMainPrice05,tvMainPrice06;
TextView tvHref01,tvHref02,tvHref03,tvHref04,tvHref05,tvHref06;
ImageView ivImage01,ivImage02,ivImage03,ivImage04,ivImage05,ivImage06;

TextView tvIdDiscout01,tvIdDiscout02,tvIdDiscout03,tvIdDiscout04,tvIdDiscout05,tvIdDiscout06,tvIdDiscout07,tvIdDiscout08;
TextView tvNameDiscout01,tvNameDiscout02,tvNameDiscout03,tvNameDiscout04,tvNameDiscout05,tvNameDiscout06,tvNameDiscout07,tvNameDiscout08;
TextView tvPriceDiscout01,tvPriceDiscout02,tvPriceDiscout03,tvPriceDiscout04,tvPriceDiscout05,tvPriceDiscout06,tvPriceDiscout07,tvPriceDiscout08;
TextView tvMainPriceDiscout01,tvMainPriceDiscout02,tvMainPriceDiscout03,tvMainPriceDiscout04,tvMainPriceDiscout05,tvMainPriceDiscout06,tvMainPriceDiscout07,tvMainPriceDiscout08;
TextView tvHrefDiscout01,tvHrefDiscout02,tvHrefDiscout03,tvHrefDiscout04,tvHrefDiscout05,tvHrefDiscout06,tvHrefDiscout07,tvHrefDiscout08;
ImageView ivImageDiscout01,ivImageDiscout02,ivImageDiscout03,ivImageDiscout04,ivImageDiscout05,ivImageDiscout06,ivImageDiscout07,ivImageDiscout08;


List<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> thumb = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> mainprice = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> href = new ArrayList<String>();


List<String> idDiscout = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> thumbDiscout = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> nameDiscout = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> priceDiscout = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> mainpriceDiscout = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> hrefDiscout = new ArrayList<String>();

ViewPager viewPager;
CustomSwipAdapter swipAdapter;


public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);



        viewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        swipAdapter = new CustomSwipAdapter(getContext());
        viewPager.setAdapter(swipAdapter);
        Log.d("View Pager",""+viewPager);

    // Special Product

    tvId01 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_id01);
    tvId02 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_id02);
    tvId03 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_id03);
    tvId04 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_id04);
    tvId05 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_id05);
    tvId06 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_id06);

    tvName01 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lineaar_layout_special_product_name01);
    tvName02 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lineaar_layout_special_product_name02);
    tvName03 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lineaar_layout_special_product_name03);
    tvName04 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lineaar_layout_special_product_name04);
    tvName05 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lineaar_layout_special_product_name05);
    tvName06 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lineaar_layout_special_product_name06);

    tvPrice01 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_price01);
    tvPrice02 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_price02);
    tvPrice03 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_price03);
    tvPrice04 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_price04);
    tvPrice05 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_price05);
    tvPrice06 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_price06);

    tvMainPrice01 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_mainprice01);
    tvMainPrice02 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_mainprice02);
    tvMainPrice03 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_mainprice03);
    tvMainPrice04 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_mainprice04);
    tvMainPrice05 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_mainprice05);
    tvMainPrice06 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_mainprice06);

    tvHref01 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_href01);
    tvHref02 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_href02);
    tvHref03 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_href03);
    tvHref04 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_href04);
    tvHref05 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_href05);
    tvHref06 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_product_href06);

    ivImage01 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_produce_image01);
    ivImage02 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_produce_image02);
    ivImage03 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_produce_image03);
    ivImage04 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_produce_image04);
    ivImage05 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_produce_image05);
    ivImage06 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_special_produce_image06);

    // Discount Session

    tvIdDiscout01 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_id01);
    tvIdDiscout02 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_id02);
    tvIdDiscout03 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_id03);
    tvIdDiscout04 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_id04);
    tvIdDiscout05 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_id05);
    tvIdDiscout06 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_id06);
    tvIdDiscout07 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_id07);
    tvIdDiscout08 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_id08);

    tvNameDiscout01 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lineaar_layout_discout_product_name01);
    tvNameDiscout02 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lineaar_layout_discout_product_name02);
    tvNameDiscout03 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lineaar_layout_discout_product_name03);
    tvNameDiscout04 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lineaar_layout_discout_product_name04);
    tvNameDiscout05 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lineaar_layout_discout_product_name05);
    tvNameDiscout06 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lineaar_layout_discout_product_name06);
    tvNameDiscout07 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lineaar_layout_discout_product_name07);
    tvNameDiscout08 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lineaar_layout_discout_product_name08);

    tvPriceDiscout01 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_price01);
    tvPriceDiscout02 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_price02);
    tvPriceDiscout03 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_price03);
    tvPriceDiscout04 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_price04);
    tvPriceDiscout05 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_price05);
    tvPriceDiscout06 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_price06);
    tvPriceDiscout07 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_price07);
    tvPriceDiscout08 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_price08);

    tvMainPriceDiscout01 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_mainprice01);
    tvMainPriceDiscout02 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_mainprice02);
    tvMainPriceDiscout03 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_mainprice03);
    tvMainPriceDiscout04 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_mainprice04);
    tvMainPriceDiscout05 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_mainprice05);
    tvMainPriceDiscout06 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_mainprice06);
    tvMainPriceDiscout07 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_mainprice07);
    tvMainPriceDiscout08 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_mainprice08);

    tvHrefDiscout01 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_href01);
    tvHrefDiscout02 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_href02);
    tvHrefDiscout03 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_href03);
    tvHrefDiscout04 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_href04);
    tvHrefDiscout05 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_href05);
    tvHrefDiscout06 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_href06);
    tvHrefDiscout07 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_href07);
    tvHrefDiscout08 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_href08);

    ivImageDiscout01 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_image01);
    ivImageDiscout02 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_image02);
    ivImageDiscout03 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_image03);
    ivImageDiscout04 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_image04);
    ivImageDiscout05 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_image05);
    ivImageDiscout06 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_image06);
    ivImageDiscout07 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_image07);
    ivImageDiscout08 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_discout_product_image08);

    new SpecialProduct().execute("http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/specialproduct&key=test123$");

    new DiscoutProduct().execute("http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/discountproduct&key=test123$");



 /*  ivImage01.setImageBitmap();
    ivImage02.setImageResource();
    ivImage03.setImageResource();
    ivImage04.setImageResource();
    ivImage05.setImageResource();
    ivImage06.setImageResource();*/


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}

public class SpecialProduct extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            int sattus = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(sattus==200){
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("sproducts");

                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                    Log.d("jsonObject length",""+jsonArray.length());

                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d("Json object value",jsonObject1+"");

                    id.add(jsonObject1.getString("product_id"));
                    thumb.add(jsonObject1.getString("thumb"));
                    name.add(jsonObject1.getString("name"));
                    price.add(jsonObject1.getString("price"));
                    mainprice.add(jsonObject1.getString("mainprice"));
                    href.add(jsonObject1.getString("href"));
                }
            }


        }catch (IOException | JSONException e){
            Log.e("Error :",e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.d("Image Array List size", thumb.size() + "");
        Log.d("id Array List size", id.size() + "");
        Log.d("name Array List size",name.size()+"");
        Log.d("price array list value",price.size()+"");
        Log.d("mainprice array list",mainprice.size()+"");
        Log.d("href array list value", href.size() + "");
        tvId01.setText(id.get(0));
        tvId02.setText(id.get(1));
        tvId03.setText(id.get(2));
        tvId04.setText(id.get(3));
        tvId05.setText(id.get(4));
        tvId06.setText(id.get(5));

        tvName01.setText(name.get(0));
        tvName02.setText(name.get(1));
        tvName03.setText(name.get(2));
        tvName04.setText(name.get(3));
        tvName05.setText(name.get(4));
        tvName06.setText(name.get(5));

        tvPrice01.setText(price.get(0));
        tvPrice02.setText(price.get(1));
        tvPrice03.setText(price.get(2));
        tvPrice04.setText(price.get(3));
        tvPrice05.setText(price.get(4));
        tvPrice06.setText(price.get(5));

        tvMainPrice01.setText(mainprice.get(0));
        tvMainPrice02.setText(mainprice.get(1));
        tvMainPrice03.setText(mainprice.get(2));
        tvMainPrice04.setText(mainprice.get(3));
        tvMainPrice05.setText(mainprice.get(4));
        tvMainPrice06.setText(mainprice.get(5));

        tvHref01.setText(href.get(0));
        tvHref02.setText(href.get(1));
        tvHref03.setText(href.get(2));
        tvHref04.setText(href.get(3));
        tvHref05.setText(href.get(4));
        tvHref06.setText(href.get(5));
      //  super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        new setImageView(ivImage01).execute(thumb.get(0));
        new setImageView(ivImage02).execute(thumb.get(1));
        new setImageView(ivImage03).execute(thumb.get(2));
        new setImageView(ivImage04).execute(thumb.get(3));
        new setImageView(ivImage05).execute(thumb.get(4));
        new setImageView(ivImage06).execute(thumb.get(5));

    }
}

public class setImageView extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    ImageView bitmap;


    public setImageView(ImageView bitmap){
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        dialog.setMessage("connecting");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

        String urldisplay = params[0];
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try{
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        }catch (IOException e ){
            e.getMessage();
            //    Log.e("Error :",e.getMessage());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        bitmap.setImageBitmap(result);
        //super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
    }
}

public class DiscoutProduct extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            int sattus = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (sattus == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dproducts");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    Log.d("jsonObject length", "" + jsonArray.length());

                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d("Json object value", jsonObject1 + "");

                    idDiscout.add(jsonObject1.getString("product_id"));
                    thumbDiscout.add(jsonObject1.getString("thumb"));
                    nameDiscout.add(jsonObject1.getString("name"));
                    priceDiscout.add(jsonObject1.getString("price"));
                    mainpriceDiscout.add(jsonObject1.getString("mainprice"));
                    hrefDiscout.add(jsonObject1.getString("href"));
                }
            }
        }catch (JSONException | IOException e){
            Log.d("Error :",e.getMessage());
        }


        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        tvIdDiscout01.setText(idDiscout.get(0));
        tvIdDiscout02.setText(idDiscout.get(1));
        tvIdDiscout03.setText(idDiscout.get(2));
        tvIdDiscout04.setText(idDiscout.get(3));
        tvIdDiscout05.setText(idDiscout.get(4));
        tvIdDiscout06.setText(idDiscout.get(5));
        tvIdDiscout06.setText(idDiscout.get(6));
        tvIdDiscout06.setText(idDiscout.get(7));

        tvNameDiscout01.setText(nameDiscout.get(0));
        tvNameDiscout02.setText(nameDiscout.get(1));;
        tvNameDiscout03.setText(nameDiscout.get(2));
        tvNameDiscout04.setText(nameDiscout.get(3));
        tvNameDiscout05.setText(nameDiscout.get(4));
        tvNameDiscout06.setText(nameDiscout.get(5));
        tvNameDiscout07.setText(nameDiscout.get(6));
        tvNameDiscout08.setText(nameDiscout.get(7));

        tvPriceDiscout01.setText(priceDiscout.get(0));
        tvPriceDiscout02.setText(priceDiscout.get(1));
        tvPriceDiscout03.setText(priceDiscout.get(2));
        tvPriceDiscout04.setText(priceDiscout.get(3));
        tvPriceDiscout05.setText(priceDiscout.get(4));
        tvPriceDiscout06.setText(priceDiscout.get(5));
        tvPriceDiscout07.setText(priceDiscout.get(6));
        tvPriceDiscout08.setText(priceDiscout.get(7));

        tvMainPriceDiscout01.setText(mainpriceDiscout.get(0));
        tvMainPriceDiscout02.setText(mainpriceDiscout.get(1));
        tvMainPriceDiscout03.setText(mainpriceDiscout.get(2));
        tvMainPriceDiscout04.setText(mainpriceDiscout.get(3));
        tvMainPriceDiscout05.setText(mainpriceDiscout.get(4));
        tvMainPriceDiscout06.setText(mainpriceDiscout.get(5));
        tvMainPriceDiscout07.setText(mainpriceDiscout.get(6));
        tvMainPriceDiscout08.setText(mainpriceDiscout.get(7));


        tvHrefDiscout01.setText(hrefDiscout.get(0));
        tvHrefDiscout02.setText(hrefDiscout.get(1));
        tvHrefDiscout03.setText(hrefDiscout.get(2));
        tvHrefDiscout04.setText(hrefDiscout.get(3));
        tvHrefDiscout05.setText(hrefDiscout.get(4));
        tvHrefDiscout06.setText(hrefDiscout.get(5));
        tvHrefDiscout07.setText(hrefDiscout.get(6));
        tvHrefDiscout08.setText(hrefDiscout.get(7));


        //  super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        new setImageView(ivImageDiscout01).execute(thumbDiscout.get(0));
        new setImageView(ivImageDiscout02).execute(thumbDiscout.get(1));
        new setImageView(ivImageDiscout03).execute(thumbDiscout.get(2));
        new setImageView(ivImageDiscout04).execute(thumbDiscout.get(3));
        new setImageView(ivImageDiscout05).execute(thumbDiscout.get(4));
        new setImageView(ivImageDiscout06).execute(thumbDiscout.get(5));
        new setImageView(ivImageDiscout07).execute(thumbDiscout.get(6));
        new setImageView(ivImageDiscout08).execute(thumbDiscout.get(7));

      //  super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}}
```

My CustomSwipAdapter.java:-

```
public class CustomSwipAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private List<String> image_path = new ArrayList<String>();
private ImageView imageView;
private List<Integer> flag= new ArrayList<Integer>();


public CustomSwipAdapter(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
    Log.d("Contruster call","");


}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    Log.d("call number","");
    return flag.size();
//    return flag.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return (view==(LinearLayout)o);
}
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swip_layout,container,false);

    imageView = (ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    new Slider().execute("http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/slider&key=test123$");



    Integer val[] = new Integer[flag.size()];

    flag.toArray(val);

 /*   imageView.setImageResource(val[position]);*/
    container.addView(item_view);

    return item_view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    // super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

public class Slider extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, Please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            int sattus = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            Log.d("Hello status","");

            if(sattus==200){
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("banners");

                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){


                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    image_path.add(jsonObject1.getString("sliderimage"));
                    flag.add(i);
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException  |JSONException e){
            Log.e("Error ",e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        dialog.cancel();
        for(int i=0;i<image_path.size();i++){
            new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute(image_path.get(i));
        }
    //    new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute(image_path);
    }
}

public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{

    ImageView bitmap;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bitmap){
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, Please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        String urldisplay = params[0];
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try{
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            return bitmap;
        }catch (IOException e ){
            e.getMessage();
        //    Log.e("Error :",e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bitmap.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}}
```

I my application image come from web server.Thanks in advance!

Comment: really i dot understand any thing from you code .. what you mean by No Exception through NullPointerException in android

Comment: mostly when view pager is not show behind reason is it's through NullPointer Exception

Comment: where you got null?? do you please post your log

Comment: No null is find then i post my question any other reason??

Comment: do you have error logcat ? please update your question with that

Comment: No i find no error in my logcat

Comment: better you debug and find out what is happening